# A good way to let a participant confirm its participation

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, mobile-application

Let's suppose a mobile application aiming to suggest some meeting to others.

One user creates a Meeting (announcement) (without invitations) and some interested users can detect it in a list of suggested meetings and participate in.

Currently, the screen showing the detail of a suggested meeting is somewhat like that:

[image]

(for the sake of the example: [UserPicture] represents the real picture of the participant, not a textual link).

Of course, some of those participants may desist at any time and others may dare participating while hesitating all day long and without showing signs of life.
Thus, I expect each participant to confirm **MANUALLY** its participation, so that others (and the creator) could know precisely which are really expected/sure to come.
It would act as an engagement.

What is a good UX way to make the user confirm?

A button ? A green check ?
Where should I place the **feature of participation confirmation**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd combine a push notification with an in-app confirmation option.

For example, if you want everyone to confirm within 6 hours before the meeting, you can send a push notification to everyone who opted in for the meeting 6 hours before the start time of the meeting. If a user clicks the notification, they are taken to the app where the top confirmation section is added.

You could also choose to make these options available in the push notification itself.

[image: Example display]

Answer (score 0):

I would send the users that are put into the participant list a notification that they have been invited, from there they can accept or decline the invitation. Something like this:
[image]

When the user then hits accept or decline the participant list can update with either the green check or red 'X' like so:

[image]

This creates a separation between the process of creating an event and adding participants, and thee participants choosing whether to attend.

Comment: Actually there's no concept of "invitation". Creator publishes the meeting he wants, and any user detecting it (in a list of announced meetings) could participate. Besides, I thought about this visual way of status, but as the names could be very large, I imagined to place the status at the very left (before the picture). Therefore this solution does not fit ;)

Comment: I updated the OP to be more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing here seems mostly semantical. If there's no specific invitation list, everyone's invited.

A simple [ i'm coming! | not interested ] set of buttons in between the event info and attendee list should suffice.

Comment: Ok:  I will try to better explain with a real case. 
Let's suppose a soccer match. A soccer match needs 22 players. Bob, the soccer match creator publishes the announcement. 22 players are interested and participate then, through a "participate" button. The frustrating thing is that some people forget to desist when they eventually can't come. So I thought about an additional confirmation to really engage the participant (let's say 6 hours before the match), so that the creator could ensure 22 players strictly. This confirmation would act as : "Be Sure I will come dude !"

Comment: Is it more clear? Then the creator would not take into account participants that has participated but NOT confirmed 6 hours before the match.

Comment: This is still the same issue, really.

[ i'm still coming | i changed my mind ]

but perhaps in a different spot, like a dropdown notifications. for example !(http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/nexus2cee_notification1.png)

Comment: Clearly not IMHO ;)

Comment: Best way to ensure people will come is to ask them few times before the event (the match) that they'll effectively come.  If you involve a "changed my mind" button, it expects user to click on it...but the main issue is that this user might not open the app at all. (forgetfulness, lazyness or other reasons). The way to detect people that will surely come is to ask them to click on a confirmation button just few hours before the event. Indeed, trusty people would be those really interested in the event and sure to come.

Comment: If you don't include a button to opt out, nobody will opt out, including those that changed their mind, so you'll have people saying they go but not actually going, which defeats the entire purpose of the app.

Comment: Obviously I already have a "desist" button. I think ( IMHO) you didn t figure out well the issue.

Comment: Is the desist button visible at the same time as the confirm button? Then it's a boolean choice like what I (and Lex) repeatedly mentioned.

Is the desist button not visible when they are asked to confirm? Then you're essentially not giving them a choice, and my last comment applies.

Comment: Desist button is visible to all participants. Confirmation button too. The point is that some (bad) people would initially participate without giving sign of life afterwards, while why not deleting the app! ... But those people would not dare clicking on "Be sure I'll really really be present dude!". So, only people that really expect to come, will open the app few hours before and click on this confirmation button. Creator would say: "Ok, so I can trust 18 users / 22 , they will effectively come since they are still...."alive"". 4 in this case have simply participated without "etiquette".

Comment: What really happens, is that on my app, there's a Chat Zone for all participants. They can talk each other in the same Chat. What happens is that the creator always send few hours before the event: "Can anybody confirm by typing "Ok" that he will really come? Thanks guys". This OP is to avoid anybody to pollute the Chat with some "Ok". I expect each one mark its status on the participants list. My OP is therefore, what is a good way to enable and display it?